# Can I go for both Tichu types in one round?

Tags: tichu

The rules seem to imply that people cannot call two or more tichus of the same kind. Doing this would also take the fun out of the game, as the first player to have a strong hand simply calls for enough tichus to reach the limit and win (or lose, if unlucky) the game.

The *grand* tichu, however, is presented as an additional mechanism. Does this mean that I can go for both and score 300 bonus points in a single round?

Comment: I'm quite sure the answer is "no", just based on common sense; but as I don't have a rules quote to this effect, I'm not making it an answer yet,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, you can only call one type of Tichu per hand.**

Honestly, I spent an inordinate amount of time looking at different rules ([here](http://www.redmeeple.com/site/images/Rules/tichu-Rules(EN).PDF), [here](http://www.gamecabinet.com/rules/Tichu.html), [here](http://www.fatamorgana.ch/tichu/tichu_english.asp), and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tichu)). Ultimately, none of these explicitly state whether a player is allowed to call both types of Tichu, but all of them imply it. I finally found one [source](http://scv.bu.edu/~aarondf/Games/Tichu/Tichu.html) with this wording after Grand Tichu:

> A single player may not call both a "Grand Tichu" and a standard "Tichu".

This seems to explicitly call out what the other rule sets imply: after calling a Grand Tichu, you cannot call a small Tichu, and vice versa (assuming you're calling a small Tichu before you see nine cards). The [website](http://scv.bu.edu/~aarondf/Games/Tichu/) these rules come from also has some strategy documents that appear to support it's claim that two Tichus cannot be called by a single player.

---

On a separate note, part of the reason this might not be explicitly called out in many rule sets is because they are translations. I don't read German, but someone might be able to verify that the rules as originally written indicate that only one Tichu can be called, and translations failed to pick up on this.

Answer (score 1):

The [official Rio Grande rules](http://riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_190_gameRules.pdf) sort of seem to imply that "tichu" and "grand tichu" are mutually exclusive.  From the "tactical hints" section of the official rules:

> Good tichu players keep an eye on the score. If the score is 630:970, for example, a grand tichu is begging to be played.

I'd argue that if players were allowed to call *both* tichu and grand tichu in the same hand, I think it would make sense for the rulebook to encourage the player in this situation to call both - but it doesn't.

For practical purposes, it might be worth considering implementing a house rule that no **single** player may call both tichu and grand tichu, but that both players *on the same team* may both call tichu or grand tichu individually (in rare cases, one player may want to "hedge" their partner's tichu).